# How can I use pem files in php's ssh2 functions

Tags: php, ssh, amazon-ec2

I need to connect to some Amazon EC2 instances through php's ssh2 functions to get some info and display it on my backoffice.

Is there a way in ssh2 functions to do the same I do when connecting through the command line ssh?

```
ssh -i path_to_file/key.pem host01-ec2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`openssl_pkey_get_public`](http://www.php.net/openssl_pkey_get_public) to extract the pub/private keys, and then use [`ssh2_auth_pubkey_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php) to authorize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (I tried that, and it works if you have both keys), but the thing is when connecting with command line's ssh I only use the private key, the public is retrieved from the host. Do yo know if I can do like that in PHP ssh functions?

Comment: That sounds odd. You usually have the public key, if you have the private one. Aren't it in your `.ssh` directory?

Comment: Yes I'm in .ssh folder, but don't worry, probably is an error of the guy that generated the pem for me... Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: No I have the same issue, it only uses the private key

Answer (score 3):

You could use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net), to do this easily enough:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
//$key->setPassword('whatever');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

phpseclib seems to support quite a few different key formats:

http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=15226

The fact that ssh2_auth_pubkey_file() requires both the public and private key is silly since 99% of the time the private key has the public key embedded within it.  But whatever - it's not like they asked me lol.

Comment: Good job. This worked for me pretty easy. This also allows to run mysqldump through which one can backup big table and whole database on remote machine from windows terminal.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can get the public key from private key

```
$eKey = file_get_contents('/pathto/key.pem');
$key_private = openssl_get_privatekey($eKey);
$keyDet=openssl_pkey_get_details($key_private);
$key_public = openssl_pkey_get_public(array($keyDet['key'],""));
$keyPDet=openssl_pkey_get_details($key_public);
```