# PHP SSH2 and Amazon EC2 .pem's

Tags: php, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've been looking for a way to use [PHP's SSH2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) to create a sort of terminal. To connect to Amazon in a normal terminal, you would use something like `ssh -i path_to/key.pem ec2.ip-555-xxx.com`. In PHP on the other hand, SSH2 has a function [ssh2_auth_pubkey_file](http://nc.php.net/ssh2_auth_pubkey_file) . But have run into a bit of a wall here, as Amazon only provides me with 1 private key (.pem) file, and the function has arguments for both private and public keys. Ultimately I'd like to have a client upload a .pem file to the server and be able to connect to a local or remote SSH server with PHP SSH2 on Amazon using that .pem file.

Comment: I found this post, but the answer didn't really help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802926/how-can-i-use-pem-files-in-phps-ssh2-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pem is the server certificate for the apache web server, it has nothing to do with ssh. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file-f

Seems it might also be a combo file with public and private keys in it. In any case it will not work for ssh directly, you will need to convert it to normal files.

You have it backward anyway - amazon will not give you the private key, quite the opposite - you give amazon the public key. You generate the private/public key pair locally, then upload the public key into the .ssh/authorize_keys files.

Comment: this helps actually! This lead me to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1645352 which worked with  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file.

Comment: actually that's exactly what Amazon gives you to first connect with your instance. It generates a private key for you to download and loads the public key to .ssh/authorized_keys. After you connect for the first time you can upload your own keys

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is correct, or correct any longer.

I just setup my Amazon instance, got my .pem file, put it in my .ssh folder and was able to ssh into my machine with this command: `ssh -i mypem.pem ec2-user@mymachine.amazonaws.com`. Since I create an SSH_config alias anyways, I just add the identifyfile for this pem file and now simply do `ssh amz` on command line.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd recommend [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) be used:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
//$key->setPassword('whatever');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the private and public keys from .pem within php

```
$eKey = file_get_contents('/pathto/key.pem');
$key_private = openssl_get_privatekey($eKey);
$keyDet=openssl_pkey_get_details($key_private);
$key_public = openssl_pkey_get_public(array($keyDet['key'],""));
$keyPDet=openssl_pkey_get_details($key_public);
```